# Basic exercises on decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I am a pure math person doing some ML self-study and I am pretty lost.

I am trying to solve the following exercises on decision trees:

> Exercise 1. Consider the following training set where
> $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are the attributes and $Y$ is the class variable.
> $$ \begin{matrix} Y & X_1 & X_2 & X_3 & X_4 \\ 1 & 0   & 1   &  0  & 1
>  \\ 1 & 1   & 0   &  1  & 0   \\ 1 & 1   & 1   &  1  & 0   \\ 1 & 0   &
>  0   &  0  & 1   \\ 1 & 1   & 1   &  1  & 0   \\ -1& 0   & 0   &  1  & 1   \\
>  -1& 0   & 0   &  0  & 0   \\
>  -1& 0   & 0   &  1  & 0   \\
>  -1& 1   & 0   &  0  & 0   \\
>  -1& 0   & 0   &  1  & 1   \\ \end{matrix} $$
>
> - Learn a decision tree using the ID3 algorithm.
> - Draw a decision tree having only 4 leaf nodes, 3 internal nodes and depth bounded by 2, that has 100% accuracy on the given dataset.

> Exercise 2. Let $x$ be a vector of $n$ Boolean variables
> ${X_1,...,X_n}$ and let $k$ be an integer less than $n$. Let $f_k$ be
> a target concept which is a disjunction consisting of $k$ literals.
> State  the  size  of  the  smallest  possible  consistent  decision
> tree  (namely  a  decision  tree  that correctly classifies all
> possible examples) for $f_k$ in terms of $n$ and $k$ and describe its shape.

Now, I've done the first part of Exersice 1 as follows: first I noticed that $X_2$ is pure and so I chose it as root; then I used Information Gain to find the nodes. The second question confuses me: my understanding was that ID3 already gives the smallest tree, so how am I supposed to make it smaller? Or if am I wrong can anybody help me clarify?

For the second problem, I really don't know where to start from, so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID3 is a heuristic. It is not guaranteed to generate an optimal decision tree.

Here is an algorithm for Exercise 1:

- If $X_3 = 1$, then answer $2X_1-1$.
- If $X_3 = 0$, then answer $2X_4-1$.

For Exercise 2, suppose $f_k = X_1 \lor \cdots \lor X_k$. An optimal decision tree simulates the following algorithm:

- If $X_1 = 1$, output 1, else continue.
- If $X_2 = 1$, output 1, else continue.
- ...
- If $X_k = 1$, output 1, else output 0.

Indeed, every decision tree for $f_k$ must query all of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ in the worst case.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! I have one more question: I understand the algorithm for exercise 1 part b, but how did you find it? Is there some quantity (like information gain) that if computed can tell me to pick $X_3$ as the root?

Comment: I just tried a few possibilities. There aren't so many.